# Why do Hadoop have different communication mechanisms for inter-datanode and datanode-namenode communication?

Tags: hadoop

The datanode-namenode communication uses the org.apache.hadoop.ipc package; while the inter-datanode communication is based on simple socket communication.

What is the motivation behind such design?

Comment: The best thing is to ask such things on the hadoop mailing lists in particular on the developer list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different tasks by their requirements so two different implementations can be explained by desire to better suit the requirements. 
DataNode -> NameNode communication is more complex then DataNode-DataNode communication and thus justify RPC.  
DataNode-DataNode communication is extremely simple in one hand, and require efficient transport of big amount of data. Can be stated that sockets is a most efficient solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaDoc, both [DatanodeProtocol](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataNode.html) and [InterDatanodeProtocol](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/protocol/InterDatanodeProtocol.html) are derived from org.apache.hadoop.ipc.VersionedProtocol.

Having said that, based on the documentation it looks like DataNode (which implements DatanodeProtocol) does a heck lot more (connections to Namenode, other data nodes & clients). Where as the communication between DataNodes (through InterDataNodeProtocol) indicates a simple communication.

Comment: Not sure why someone thought this response is not helpful but let me explain. The question was Datanode-namenode communication uses org.apache.hadoop.ipc packge and I was merely pointing out that both the communication OP Posted was based on the same package. It does seem that having the same package has nothing to do with the types of communication between the DataNode and Namenode.